# Firebase cloud functions fails on using array's values function

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I create a firebase functions project using typescript, es2017 target, and node 8 version.

I'm trying to use the syntax:

```
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const iterator = items.values();
```

But it fails with: **items.values is not a function**

I use this syntax in NodeJs, but fire the same error...

Does someone know what I want the setup to solve it?

Comment: Apparently the runtime you're on doesn't implement `Array.values()`. Are you sure you [set the runtime to be Node 8](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/cloud-functions-for-firebase-config-node-8-timeout-memory-region.html) (afaik the default is still Node 6)?

Comment: Yeah, on administrative page I can see "Run time: Node.js 8 (Beta)" description. But even in node cli this errors is fired.

Comment: I actually don't know in what runtimes `Array.values()` was introduced, but the compatibility table at the bottom of this page says it was added in Node 10.9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values#Browser_compatibility.

Comment: Locally, if I using  `node --harmony-array-prototype-values`, on CLI Array.values works (my node is v9.5.0). But I don't know like use it on a cloud functions.

Comment: How about running Node 8 locally, which is the most recent version Cloud Functions supports (afaik)?

Comment: I tried this but got the same result

Answer (score 2):

I solved it including polyfills:

1 -  Installing core-js package: `npm i cores-js --save`

2 - Creating polyfills.ts file with

```
import "core-js/es6/symbol";
import "core-js/es6/object";
import "core-js/es6/function";
import "core-js/es6/parse-int";
import "core-js/es6/parse-float";
import "core-js/es6/number";
import "core-js/es6/math";
import "core-js/es6/string";
import "core-js/es6/date";
import "core-js/es6/array";
import "core-js/es6/regexp";
import "core-js/es6/map";
import "core-js/es6/set";
import "core-js/es6/reflect";
import "core-js/es7/reflect";
```

3 - Include polyfills.ts file import on index.ts

import './polyfills';